How to link VCPKG libraries with G++
I have got vcpkg fully installed and working (installed in C:/vcpkg) and I have installed a library I want to use, in this case, cppzmq/zmq (ZeroMQ).
The header files and .lib files are present in C:/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/include and C:/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/lib, but when I try to link them to a C++ project using G++ it cannot find them. ("cannot find -lzmq: No such file or directory")
The vcpkg filetree:
├───include
│       zmq.h
│       zmq.hpp
│       zmq_addon.hpp
│       zmq_utils.h
│
├───lib
│       libzmq-mt-4_3_5.lib

This is the command I am using:
g++ src/main.cpp -o main -IC:/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/include -LC:/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/lib -lzmq

I have also tried with -lcppzmq, -lzmq-mt, and -lcppzmq-mt.
How would I go about tackling this problem? I am not using CMake or MSBuild tools, and I would prefer to avoid using such.

From here: For Windows users, Visual Studio's MSVC (Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler) is the required compiler for C++ development..

@trojanfoe mingw is supported

@AlanBirtles Ah indeed; it would be good to get some clarity from the OP then on which mingw triplets they are using.

a) With GCC you don't want to use x64-windows as a triplet. Use the mingw (e.g. x64-mingw-dynamic) triplets. The x64-windows is the default one if you did not specify one. You can specify another triplet by e.g. --host-triplet x64-mingw-dynamic
b) Given the filename you probably would have needed -lzmq-mt-4_3_5 however I strongly suggest a different approach from manually invoking the compiler
